# Hdmi to Display Port connection

Tags: hdmi, display-port, cable, video-adapters

I'm looking for a way to connect my MacBook Pro with one cable to my monitor.
On Monitor side, only available port is Display Port.
Currently I'm using 2 cables - one is connecting computer directly with monitor (Mini DisplayPort / USBC to Display Port), and second one goes via powered hub to some accessories (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32821301992.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.0.0.4fe31802B2WcL0)

The Hub has HDMI output - which I could switch to if only I knew a good way to go from HDMI to Display Port.
After some researches I found it is more common to have Display Port -> Hdmi Cables (one dirrecitonal) and when searching for the other way around - it seems there are not many (if any) good product.

I would like to be able to achieve 2560x1440 resolution (native for my display) with some decent refresh rate (120Hz, 144Hz would be nice).

I have seen things like this:
https://aliexpress.com/item/32554067741.html
but I don't know if they are worth the money.

I would love to get some ideas from people who tried such connection and what connection / accessories did you use.

I'm aware (thanks to Romen) that I would need to replace the hub with something better than HDMI 1.4, but for now, the main problem is how to get from HDMI to DisplayPort with the best possible/available solution.

Comment: What is the model of the hub you are using?

Comment: I have this one:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32821301992.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.0.0.4fe31802B2WcL0
But also a different one from a different vendor, but basically with similar inputs/outputs

Comment: Update the question with that information.

Comment: The hub you have will not support 2560x1440 at 120hz. HDMI 1.4 does not have enough bandwidth.